# Multithreading execution time with sum of random numbers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, execution-time

I'm attempting to create a multithreaded program which sums an array of N random numbers [-100,100] with K worker threads that are serialized by a programmer-implemented spinlock (busy wait). Before I attempted to use random numbers, for testing purposes, I initialized the whole array with 1s, as you'll see in my code. Since I have no clue whatsoever on where the issue is, I'll post the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

struct lock {

    long double sum = 0;
    atomic_flag m_flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // Inicializa com m_flag = 0

    void acquire() {
        while(m_flag.test_and_set());
    }
    void release() {
        m_flag.clear();
    }
};

struct t_data{
    int t_id;
    char* sumArray;
    struct lock* spinlock;
};

void* sum(void* thread_data) {

    struct t_data *my_data;
    long double m_sum=0;
    my_data = (struct t_data *) thread_data; 

    for (int i=0;i<strlen(my_data->sumArray);i++) {
        m_sum += my_data->sumArray[i];
    }

    my_data->spinlock->acquire();
    cout << "THREAD ID: " << my_data->t_id << endl;
    cout << "Acquired lock." << endl;
    my_data->spinlock->sum += m_sum;
    cout << "Releasing lock..." << endl << endl;
    my_data->spinlock->release();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Inicializar cronômetro, arrays, spinlock,etc.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            , spinlock, etc. 
    system_clock::time_point starting_time = system_clock::now();
    int K = atoi(argv[1]);
    int N = atoi(argv[2]);
    int temp;
    double expected_sum = 0;
    pthread_t threads[K];
    struct t_data threads_data[K];
    struct lock spinlock;
    const long int numElements = (long int) N/K;  //Divisão inteira de N/K para dividir array em parcelas

    // Criar array[K] de arrays para delegar cada sub-lista a uma thread
    char** numArrays = new char*[K]; 
    for(int i=0;i<K;i++)
        numArrays[i] = new char[numElements];  //Char utilizado para que seja alocado apenas 1 byte por número

    // Inicializar seed aleatória para preenchimento de arrays
    srand(time(NULL)); 

    //Preencher arrays que serão passados às threads criadas
    for (int i=0;i<K;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<numElements;j++) {
            temp = 1;//rand() % 201 - 100; (CHANGING THIS GIVES UNEXPECTED RESULTS)
            numArrays[i][j] = temp;
            expected_sum+=temp;
        }
        //Criar threads e passando argumentos(id,spinlock,array)
        threads_data[i].t_id = i;
        threads_data[i].spinlock = &spinlock;
        threads_data[i].sumArray = numArrays[i];
        pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,sum,(void*)&threads_data[i]);
    }

    // Parar o programa até que todas as threads terminem para imprimir soma correta
    for (int i=0;i<K;i++){
        if(pthread_join(threads[i],NULL)) cout << "Error waiting for threads." << endl;
    }

    // Somando últimos valores restantes no caso de N%K != 0 (esta parcela torna-se irrelevante à medida que N >> K)
    for(int i=0;i<(int)N%K;i++) {
        temp = 1;//rand() % 201 - 100; (CHANGING THIS GIVES UNEXPECTED RESULTS)
        spinlock.sum+=temp;
        expected_sum+=temp;
    }

    // Printar resultado esperado, o calculado e tempo de execução
    cout << "EXPECTED SUM = " << expected_sum << endl;
    cout << "CALCULATED SUM = " << spinlock.sum << endl;

    // Liberar memória alocada
    for(int i=0;i<K;i++)
        delete[] numArrays[i];

    delete[] numArrays;

    auto start_ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(starting_time);
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto now_ms = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(now);
    auto value = now_ms - start_ms;
    long execution_time = value.count();
    cout << "-----------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Execution time: " << execution_time << "ms" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That works nicely on calculating the sum but poses a problem with execution time: it's supposed to linearly scale with (N/K), but testing for K=10, N=10⁶:

```
EXPECTED SUM = 1e+06
CALCULATED SUM = 1e+06
-----------------------
Execution time: 1310ms
```

And K=10, N=2*10⁶:

```
EXPECTED SUM = 2e+06
CALCULATED SUM = 2e+06
-----------------------
Execution time: 7144ms
```

I don't know why that happens. It should double. Changing K works properly. Also, if I use `rand() % 201-100` instead of 1 things get really messed up. For K=10,N=10⁶:

```
EXPECTED SUM = -16307
CALCULATED SUM = 1695
-----------------------
Execution time: 95ms
```

And regarding execution time changes, N is fixed (scales linearly) but K makes no difference anymore. None of these make sense to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen(my_data->sumArray)` will stop at the first `0` in the character array / c-string while you keep on summing up `temp` values for `expected_sum`. Use a `vector` for non-ascii data (this is C++ after all):

```
// use a vector in t_data
struct t_data{
    int t_id;
    std::vector<char> sumArray;
    lock* spinlock;
};

// adjust summing up in sum(void* thread_data)
for (char value : my_data->sumArray) {
    m_sum += value;
}

// initialise like this
threads_data[i].sumArray.resize(numElements);
for(size_t j = 0; j < threads_data[i].sumArray.size(); ++j) {
    char temp = 1; //or (char)(rand() % 201 - 100);
    threads_data[i].sumArray[j] = temp;
    expected_sum += temp;
}
```

Now consider what you're timing: move the initialisation of `threads_data[i]` and `expected_sum` outside of the timing region, otherwise the millions of `rand` calls will surely dominate everything. In any case you're measuring the sequential version together with the parallel version, so you can't expect `K` to make a difference in timing: you're always measuring at least the sequential version + the last parallel version (when joining).

Comment: Didn't know `strlen` had that issue when you represent `int` with `char`. As for the execution time, you're right. I started keeping track of parallel execution only and now both `K` and `N` make time scale linearly. Thanks!